# .hide() doesn't affect dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
<script>
$('#closeDiv').hide();
    $('#addDiv').click(function (){
    var $newdiv1 = $('<div id="main_content4"><br /><button class="close">Close this</button></p><p>Ajoutez une div avec jQuery. Cacher le bouton qui permet de l\'ajouter, ensuite ajoutez un bouton dans la nouvelle div pour la fermer à son tour. Pour finir on affiche à nouveau le bouton pour afficher la div.</p></div>'),
     existingdiv1 = document.getElementById('main_content3');

     $('#main').append($newdiv1);
     $('#addDiv').hide();
     $('#closeDiv').show();
});

$('#closeDiv').click(function()  { 
    $('#main_content4').remove();
    $('#addDiv').show();
    $('#closeDiv').hide();
});
</script>
```

As you can see in my `var $newdiv1` I create this button:

```
<button class="close">Close this</button>
```

But when I add this, it doesn't work:

```
$('#close').click(function()  { 
    $('#main_content4').remove();
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your English is completely understandable. However, "not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. It looks like this code could lead to the DOM having multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid HTML. Try using a class instead of `id="main_content4"`.

Comment: Bad code
$('.close').click(function()  { 
    $('#main_content4').remove();
});

Comment: use `.close` instead of `#close` as the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to attach event before the element has been created. To attach event to newly created element you need either directly attach it in same place where you create it, or use listeners like jQuery `.on`.

Comment: Thanks to every body !! 
I don't really understand delegation so I put my code where I create the new element and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 2):

Use delegation:

```
$('#main').on('click','.close',function()  { 
    $('#main_content4').remove();
});
```

But wait, maybe no delagation is needed only your selector was wrong:

```
$('.close').click(function()  { 
    $('#main_content4').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all this rapid answer ... But if i change only my selector, always wrong so maybe I must try the delegation...

Comment: So, d.sergeiev answer works for you? But he just post same workaround than me. Really strange...